# A template can pass argument types without loss of information

Tags: c++

Straustrup speaks about the template arguments being passed without loss of information in his book, **The C++ programming language**, "A template can pass argument types without loss of information;"

What does he mean by loss of information here ?

```
template <typename T>
T sum (T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;

}

int main ()
{
  long l = 212;
  sum<short> (l, l);
}
```

Visual C++ 11 compiler returns a warning

`warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'long' to 'short', possible loss of data`

Is this what he is referring to ?

Answer (score 3):

In writing `sum<short> (l, l);` you are insisting that the compiler calls the `short` version of `sum`: i.e. `short sum (short a, short b)`

In doing that, the `l`s are converted to `short` types. *That* is what your compiler is warning you about: you're only a hair's breadth away from *undefined behaviour* if `l` is too big for a `short`.  This process is nothing to do with the template function itself, so Stroustrup's assertion still holds: there is no loss of type information at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

If you wanted to make a generic `sum` function with out using template you would **need** to choose a particular type for implementation. This forces type-conversion, ergo possible loss of information.

The template let's you write `sum(l,l)` for *any* type and you don't lose anything. You can write `sum(string1, string2)`, no problem. In other words. Inside the sum definition you know the original type of the operand.

By choosing the type explicitly you purposely disable this mechanism, by forcing compiler into using an instantiation of your choice. This is no different than writing `sum` with explicit type. In your case you accidentally force type narrowing. But the actual types used do not matter.

His words were not about integer conversion. At least I would presume so. Templates are more important and have bigger purpose than avoiding type narrowing.

Comment: I think you get the warning since you're forcing a conversion to a narrowing type. sum<long long> would not issue a warning.

Comment: Yeah sure, for this particular case. But the reason there is an error in the 1st place is because there is a type conversion. I'll try rewording it to make myself clearer.

Comment: A *narrowing* type conversion.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it could be `string` instead of `short`. The error would be different. The thing is, that IMO, templates alleviate type conversion at all. The particular message is for the particular case. But templates are about every type not just `long` and `short`. I am not talking about this particular case, I am trying to talk about a general case.

Comment: @Bathseba E.g. such a loss of information might be also represented by slicing if we were talking about derived classes and some common `sum` for a base class. There would be no error or warning at all, and still loss of information.

Answer (score 0):

His point might be better illustrated by making a small modification to the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
T sum (T a, T b)
{
    std::cout << "summing two values of type: " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    return a + b;

}

int main ()
{
    long l = 212;
    sum(l, l);

    short s = 212;
    sum(s, s);
}
```

example output: (may be different if you're on Visual Studio)

```
summing two values of type: l
summing two values of type: s
```

Note that the full type information is available within each instantiation of the template function. This allows the compiler to perform full type-checking at compile time, decreasing the chance of a programming error that needs to be caught at run time.

Answer (score 0):

He is not refering to values but to the **type** of argument. In your example type T will be short int, it will not be changed. This allows compilers to perform various optimizations - like inlining, and also makes type safety better.

you can verify that type is preserved using below trick with TD template:

```
template<typename T> class TD;

template <typename T>
T sum (T a, T b)
{
    TD<T> aaa;
    return a + b;

}

int main ()
{
  long l = 212;
  sum<short> (l, l);
}
```

compiler will issue an error giving you information of what type T actually is, for gcc that would be:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'T sum(T, T) [with T = short int]':
main.cpp:14:19:   required from here
main.cpp:6:11: error: 'TD<short int> aaa' has incomplete type
     TD<T> aaa;
```

T = short int

so type is preserved